# Finding errors from Rails collection<< association assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the event that `collection<<` for a `has_many` association on Rails fails, how to find the errors?

For example:

```rb
@author.books << @book1
```

If this was to fail, how to catch the errors and return to user?

Thanks

Comment: Have you already looked into `begin... rescue`?

Comment: @jvillian it doesnt actually error. Transaction is rolled back

Comment: Have you tried rescuing `ActiveRecord::Rollback`? According to the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html), with the `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception, "the database transaction will be rolled back, without passing on the exception."

Comment: @jvillian doesn't work

Comment: Do you have an example of how the operation fails? In the obvious case where ``@book1`` is ``nil``, it generates an ``ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`` error, which I was able to rescue even inside a transaction.

Comment: What is failing? @book1 or @author? If the former, than use `author.books << @book1 if @book1.valid?` The errors will be in @book1.errors